# When was the last time Hamas acted against a UN resolution?

Tags: international-law, israel, united-nations, hamas

[From twitter:](https://twitter.com/giladerdan1/status/1724905990284271686)

> The @UN  Security Council’s resolution is disconnected from reality
> and is meaningless. Regardless of what the Council decides, Israel
> will continue acting according to int’l law while the Hamas terrorists
> will not even read the resolution at all, let alone abide by it. It is
> unfortunate that the Council continues to ignore, not condemn, or even
> mention the massacre that Hamas carried out on October 7, which led to
> the war in Gaza. It is truly shameful!
>
> Hamas's strategy is to deliberately deteriorate the humanitarian
> situation in the Gaza Strip and increase the number of Palestinian
> casualties in order to motivate the UN and the Security Council to
> stop Israel.
>
> It will not happen. Israel will continue to act until Hamas is
> destroyed and the hostages are returned.

An Israeli representative suggested that Hamas never ever respected any UN resolution against it, let alone read one. Now, Israel is known to have ignored UN resolutions in the past. I am guessing the same could be said about Hamas, but I wasn't sure so I thought about asking it here since people are more knowledgeable on Hamas than me. When was the last time Hamas acted against a UN resolution?

Comment: "the *last* time" is pretty opinion based. 2 seconds ago? 1 millisecond?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the 4th of November 2023.

On the 27th OCTOBER 2023 the UN General Assembly adopted a

> **Resolution Calling for Immediate, Sustained Humanitarian Truce Leading
> to Cessation of Hostilities between Israel, Hamas** ([UN press](https://press.un.org/en/2023/ga12548.doc.htm))

According to the Jerusalem Post, on the 4th of November, IDF tried to open a safe corridor, was attacked by Hamas.

The article doesn't mention whether Hamas agreed to cease fire and not to attack the humanitarian corridor:

> The IDF has been operating on the ground in Gaza for a week. The IDF
> had informed residents that the Salah al-Din route, a major road
> running from Gaza City to southern Gaza, could be used for
> humanitarian transit by civilians. “While the IDF was opening a
> humanitarian axis for the movement of Gaza residents to the south,
> terrorists from the terrorist organization Hamas attacked the forces
> involved in opening it,” the IDF said. ([JPOST](https://www.jpost.com/middle-east/article-771706))

and

> Hamas exploited this and used mortars and artillery to prevent it from
> being opened to the movement of civilians.

Answer (score 10):

Hamas has consistently acted against the UN resolutions. The most flagrant violation is the call to obliteration or dissolution of Israel. Note that Israel was created in accordance to the UN resolution. The call to obliteration or dissolution of Israel has been routinely acted upon by the targeted killing of Jewish civilians in Israel.

**References:**

> By resolution 181 (II), the Assembly decided to partition Palestine into two states, one Arab and one Jewish, with Jerusalem placed under a special international regime.

*[General Assembly - Question of Palestine](https://www.un.org/unispal/data-collection/general-assembly/)*

---

> The charter states that "our struggle against the Jews is very great and very serious" and calls for the eventual creation of an Islamic state in Palestine, in place of Israel and the Palestinian Territories, and the obliteration or dissolution of Israel. It emphasizes the importance of jihad, stating in article 13, "There is no solution for the Palestinian question except through Jihad. Initiatives, proposals and international conferences are all a waste of time and vain endeavors." The charter also states that Hamas is humanistic, and tolerant of other religions as long as they "stop disputing the sovereignty of Islam in this region". The Charter adds that "renouncing any part of Palestine means renouncing part of the religion [of Islam]". The original charter was criticized for its violent language against all Jews, which many commentators have characterized as incitement to genocide.

*[Hamas Charter - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamas_Charter)*

---

[image: Map circulated by Hamas. Data regarding the Palestinian diaspora and the refugee camps current for 2000 appears on the right.]

Map circulated by Hamas. Note that there is no Israel on the map. Data regarding the Palestinian diaspora and the refugee camps current for 2000 appears on the right.

*[Palestinian Maps Omitting Israel](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/palestinian-maps-omitting-israel)*

Answer (score 8):

The following security council resolutions come to mind:

- [1820](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_1820) "condemns the use of sexual violence as a tool of war". Hamas has used rape as tool of war in their 7.10. massacre.
- [2573](https://www.securitycouncilreport.org/un_documents_type/security-council-resolutions/page/1?ctype=Protection+of+Civilians&cbtype=protection-of-civilians#038;cbtype=protection-of-civilians) condemns "attacks on civilian infrastructure". Hamas regularly fires missiles specifically at civilian infrastructure with no military application.

More recently, there is the general assembly resolution [ES-10/21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_ES-10/21), which called for all parties to "fully comply with their obligations under international law". Hamas has continued to use human shields, have not released kidnapped civilian, and continue to shoot rockets at civilian infrastructure.

There's also the [security council resolution 2712](https://palestine.un.org/en/252895-security-council-calls-urgent-extended-humanitarian-pauses-gaza) calling for the "release of all hostages held by Hamas and other groups, especially children", which Hamas has not done.

Answer (score 4):

Since the [elephant in the room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_the_room) is the attack on October 7th, 2023, one would be served well to point out that the methods of the attack included deliberate targeting of unarmed Israeli civilians, including women, children and the elderly.  Also rape appeares to have been used as a method of assault.

All of these are violations of the Geneva Conventions.

The UN, for example, has called on all parties in all armed conflicts to **avoid intentional targeting (not to be confused with "harming" or "incidental harming")** of civilians in all armed conflicts in [resolution 1265 from 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_1265).